# form enctype slim framework

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, multipartform-data, slim

Hello so I currently have a working form for submission in slim framework. This is how my html looks like:

```
<form method="POST" action="/user/register-link">
<input type="text" name="txt_fname"> <br />
<input type="text" name="txt_lname"> <br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And in my routes:

```
$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
parse_str($request->getBody(), $output);
echo $output['txt_fname'];
echo $output['txt_lname'];
```

All the code above is actually working. Now if I want to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in my form and another `<input type="file" name="filename">` inside the form, when I try to submit I get an error of `Undefined index: txt_fname`. What is the possible mistake in my code?

Comment: `parse_str` is for data that is send as `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` (which is the implicit default, if the attribute is not set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use Slim-built-in functionality to get all Post params: `$request->post();`

If your file will not shown there you may need to use `$_FILES` to handle that file upload.